# Center LinearLayout to screen, fill space above with ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to recreate this:

[image]

I need a `LinearLayout` that is centered to the screen. The space above the `LinearLayout` should be filled out (besides some padding) with the `ImageView`.

For example, if the screen were smaller than the one in the picture above, the `ImageView` should resize accordingly, like:

[image]

How can I do this?

Here is a template I created to get myself started:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a RelativeLayout to be able to position the LinearLayout in the center of the screen and the image above it.

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

makes sure the LinearLayout is in the center of the screen.

```
android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

make sure the ImageView is above the LinearLayout and horizontially centered.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

make sure the image is scaled to fill the space above the LinearLayout without changing the aspect ratio.

Use android:src instead of android:background for the ImageView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you put `LinearLayout` above `ImageView`?

Comment: In older Android versions Views needed to be declared before they could be referenced. I'm not sure when that changed. I guess old habits don't die easily ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/center_layout"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="asdasdasdas"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That seems to almost be right, but the `ImageView` is stretching to the full width.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="center"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView inside Linear Layout"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result

[image]